# Tenho como montar uma página de upload, que possa receber fotos, vídeo e pacotes zip contendo fotos e/ou vídeos?

Tags: javascript, html5, asp.net-mvc-5, postgresql, razor

Estou como uma aplicação onde o usuário cadastrado possui uma página de uploads de imagens e vídeos e queria saber se tem como, além de receber fotos e vídeos por uploads, se eu posso receber pacotes zips com fotos e vídeos, onde, a aplicação consiga tirar esses pacotes do zip pra poder nomear e depois alocar esses arquivos no servidor. Estou utilizando ASP.NET MVC 5, razor e alguns recursos em javascripts.

Answer (score 0):

Sim. Utilizando o mesmo input file. Somente mude a forma de tratamento do arquivo no lado do servidor dependendo da extensão do arquivo.

Salve o arquivo e manipule utilizando a referencia do System.IO.

Referencie um componente de extração do ZIP como DotNetZip 1.10.1 (Nuget Pack)

```
  using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(PathDoArquivo))
  {
    foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)
    {
      e.Extract();
    }
  }
```